# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'mstUsermaster' available as request attribute

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl

**I am trying a login process using jstl taglib. Below is my controller portion code**

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/authentication", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login(@ModelAttribute("mstUsermaster")MstUsermaster mstUsermaster, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {

    MstUsermaster usermaster=loginService.authenticateUser(mstUsermaster);

    if(mstUsermaster != null ){
        System.out.println("You Are a Valid User "+mstUsermaster.getName());
        model.addAttribute("mstUsermaster1",usermaster);

    }else{
        model.addAttribute("loginMessage", "You have entered Wrong UserName or Password!");
        return "index";
    }
    return "dashboard";
}
```

jsp page (relevant part)

```
<form:form method="POST" id ="loginForm" action="${contextPath}/authentication" class="form-signin" modelAttribute="mstUsermaster">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="text-uppercase">Username</label>
                        <form:input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" path="userName"  name="username" required="" />
                        <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" id="userName" name="userName"> -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="text-uppercase">Password</label>
                        <form:input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" path="password" id="password" name="password" required=""  onkeypress="enterKeyPress(event);"/>
                        <!-- <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="" id="password" name="password"> -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input type="button" name="submit" class="btn btn-login pull-right" value="Login" id="login">
                        <!-- <button type="submit" class="btn btn-login pull-right">Login</button> -->
                    </div>
                </form:form>
```

appconfig-data.xml (relevant part)

```
<!-- Customer Data Access Object -->
<bean id="applicationContextProvder"  class="com.mistraining.isgpp.util.ApplicationContextProvider"/>

<bean id="loginDao" class="com.mistraining.isgpp.dao.impl.LoginDaoImpl" />
<bean id="loginService"class="com.mistraining.isgpp.service.impl.LoginServiceImpl"/>
<bean id="mstUsermaster" class="com.mistraining.isgpp.model.MstUsermaster"/>
```

But I still getting this error

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] threw exception
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain
>   target object for bean name 'mstUsermaster' available as request
>   attribute     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.(BindStatus.java:144)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:154)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:141)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:132)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:116)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:422)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:84)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.views.index_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(index_jsp.java:352)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.views.index_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(index_jsp.java:287)
>     at org.apache.jsp.views.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:219)   at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)    at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)  at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:467)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:392)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:209)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:267)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1221)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1005)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:952)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

How to solve this error? plz help me out

Answer (score 0):

You've got this error because your mstUsermaster  is not bound to the model

try this

```
@ModelAttribute("mstUsermaster")
public MstUsermaster  getMstUsermaster(){
    return new MstUsermaster  ();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

while loading your login page please add below in your controller.

```
model.addAttribute("mstUsermaster", new MstUsermaster());
```

Comment: tried out this one but not working getting the same error log

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `BindingResult bindingResult`, if it worked then think about it should be here or not, because `BindingResult` seems at wrong place.

Comment: Tried out this one also it didn't work for me. Getting the same error log details like previously.